# Center align of a text in a table in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, center-align

I am writing readme for a repository in gitlab, Although I do everything the same as tutorial I have couldnt center align some text in a table
here is the code Im using

```
### Qualitative Result

|    Fake     |   Real  |
|:---:|:---:|
| <img src='an address' align="center" width=400 >|<img src='another address' align="center" width=400 >|
```

however `Fake` and `Real` will not be center aligned.[image: screen shot of what I got]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **headers** are always left-aligned in Chrome and Firefox, and centered in Safari. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#tables, in the blue box.